# Using javascript & custom validator to check start date and finish date?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, validation, customvalidator

I am trying to validate a start date and finish date so that if a finish date entered by a user is before the start date it will throw up an error. I am doing this using JavaScript and the custom validator but get a runtime error saying 'CheckDate is undefined'.

I think this shouldn't be hard to solve as the code looks ok think I'm just missing something.

Any help would be great.

Here is my JavaScript, it is in script tags just haven't copied them over

```
function CheckDate(sender, args) {
    if (new date (document.getElementById("txtstartdate").value)
        > new (document.getElementById("TxtFinish").value)) {
        args.IsValid = false;
        return;
    }
    args.IsValid = true;
}
```

Here is the validation on my FinishDate control

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator29" runat="server" 
ErrorMessage="Finish Date should be greater than the Start Date" ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate"></asp:CustomValidator>
```

Need any more info ask away :).

Comment: also you need to specify the `ControlToValidate` attribute for `CustomValidator`

Comment: Which control would I validate?

Comment: I still get the error 'Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'CheckDate' is undefined'

Comment: Is your CheckDate function is embedded your page, or added dynamically from codebehind ?

Comment: `if (new Date(document.getElementById("txtstartdate").value.getDate())
 > new Date(document.getElementById("TxtFinish").value.getDate()))` ,
 javascript is case sensitive replace `date` with `Date` and add `getDate()` which returns the Date  and ignores the time, may be during runtime the CheckDate is not available .

Comment: The checkdate function is on the same page as my start and finish controls

Comment: I still get the error with your code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use a CompareValidator!

```
  <asp:CompareValidator ID="CompareValidator1" runat="server" 
    ControlToCompare="txtStartDate" ControlToValidate="txtEndDate" 
    Display="Static" ErrorMessage="'End Date' must not be earlier than 'From Date'"  Text="*"
    Operator="GreaterThanEqual" SetFocusOnError="True" Type="Date" 
    ValidationGroup="SearchGroup">
```

Comment: I think I forgot the controltovalidate :-)

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I did, and it validates perfectly.  Since I wasn't sure exactly what kind of control you were using, I just used a basic text box.  I would enter values like "July 21, 1983 01:15:00".

JavaScript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

        function CheckDate(sender, args) {

            var startDate = new Date(document.getElementById("txtStartDate").value);

            var finishDate = new Date(document.getElementById("txtFinishDate").value);

            if (startDate > finishDate) {
                args.IsValid = false;
            }
            else {
                args.IsValid = true;
            }
        }

    </script>
```

HTML:

```
<asp:CustomValidator ID="CustomValidator29" runat="server" 
    ErrorMessage="Finish Date should be greater than the Start Date" 
    ClientValidationFunction="CheckDate" ControlToValidate="txtStartDate">
</asp:CustomValidator>

<asp:TextBox id="txtStartDate" runat="server" />
<asp:TextBox id="txtFinishDate" runat="server" />
```

Here's a table of values and results:

txtStartDate: July 21, 1983 01:15:00
txtEndDate: July 25, 1983 01:15:00
Valid: Yes

txtStartDate: July 25, 1983 01:15:00
txtEndDate: July 21, 1983 01:15:00
Valid: No

txtStartDate: July 21, 1983 01:15:00
txtEndDate: July 21, 1983 06:15:00
Valid: Yes

txtStartDate: July 21, 1983 06:15:00
txtEndDate: July 21, 1983 01:15:00
Valid: No